# How to replace section of url based on form input

Tags: php, forms, url, post, replace

I found a few examples on here & that's what I'm basing my code on. But it's missing one piece. I need to add "&next=http://facebook.com" to the end of a URL string so that the end result ends in:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=########&next=http://facebook.com

(######## = input data)

So far, this is what I have:

> < ?php
>   if (isset($_POST['bt']))
>   {
>       header("Location: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=" . $_POST['folder']  );
>   }
>
> ?>
>
> < html>
>
> < form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
>
> > ```
> > < input type="text" name="folder" id="folder" />
> > < input type="submit" name="bt" id="bt" value="Go To" />
> > ```
> >
> > < /form>
> >     < /html>

Comment: I am not a PHP programmer, but I am sure it has a string joining function.

Comment: @Verbeia he uses the concatenation operator in the code.  This question is not clear to me.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['bt'])) {
    $newLocation = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=".$_POST['folder'];
    $newLocation .= "&next=http://facebook.com";
    header("Location: " . $newLocation);
}
?>
```

You can also concatenate it all in one line (like below).  Personally I like breaking it up like the one above, but - it's all up to the programmer.

```
$newLocation = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=".$_POST['folder'] . "&next=http://facebook.com";
```

Comment: Np.  If you found the answer helpful, please remember to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['bt'])) {
    $newLocation = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?' . 
    http_build_query(array('app_id' => $_POST['folder'], 'next' => 'http://facebook.com'));
    header("Location: " . $newLocation);
}
```